# create a txt file with incremental numbers

Tags: variables, batch-file, intervals, incremental-build

sorry for the question I am a total beginner in programming and probably this is very easy for someone who knows what to do:

I need to create, into a txt file, a serie of links with incremental numbers, for example I want to keep a certain part "fixed" and a part has to change; for example imagine this:

http://user:password@website.com/members/sets/001/somethingfixed-001.zip
in the text the following lines should be:

http://user:password@website.com/members/sets/002/somethingfixed-002.zip
etc..

I think there must be a way to generate those where I could specify, create the link keep the fixed part equal in every line and then incrementally put 001, 002, 003, up to the point i need it.

it could be awesome if I could create a .bat file that would ask me: what is the initial link, what is the part to be fixed and what to change.

I'd do the program like this:

insert the first link, and I paste it.

then it asks me for what is the fixed part and I put:
.../members/sets/X/somethingfixed-Y.zip

what is the range for the variables X and Y?
starting number? and I put 001 and then it asks me what is the end number? and i put 150
and it generates the links in the txt file so that I can use them.

Hope it is clear.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

#### Example

This will do it for the first number `X`, I will leave some of it for you to develop and learn. **`:)`**

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
echo LeftXRight Gen
set /p "Left=Left = "
set /p "Right=Right = "
set /p "Start=Begin = "
set /p "End=End = "
>output.txt ( <nul set /p "=" )
for /L %%A in (%Start%, 1, %End%) do (
    set "X=00%%A"
    echo !Left!!X:~-3!!Right!>>output.txt
)
endlocal
```

#### Output

```
LeftXRight Gen
Left = http://user:password@website.com/members/sets/
Right = /somethingfixed.zip
Start = 1
End = 10
```

#### output.txt

```
http://user:password@website.com/members/sets/001/somethingfixed.zip
http://user:password@website.com/members/sets/002/somethingfixed.zip
http://user:password@website.com/members/sets/003/somethingfixed.zip
http://user:password@website.com/members/sets/004/somethingfixed.zip
http://user:password@website.com/members/sets/005/somethingfixed.zip
http://user:password@website.com/members/sets/006/somethingfixed.zip
http://user:password@website.com/members/sets/007/somethingfixed.zip
http://user:password@website.com/members/sets/008/somethingfixed.zip
http://user:password@website.com/members/sets/009/somethingfixed.zip
http://user:password@website.com/members/sets/010/somethingfixed.zip
```

---

### Update

Added this complete solution to the question.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
echo LeftXMidXRight Gen
set /p "Left=Left = "
set /p "Middle=Middle = "
set /p "Right=Right = "
set /p "Start=Begin = "
set /p "End=End = "
>output.txt ( <nul set /p "=" )
for /L %%A in (%Start%, 1, %End%) do (
    set "X=00%%A"
    echo !Left!!X:~-3!!Middle!!X:~-3!!Right!>>output.txt
)
endlocal
```

#### Example

```
LeftXMidXRight Gen
Left = http://user:password@website.com/members/sets/
Middle = /somethingfixed-
Right = .zip
Begin = 1
End = 150
```

#### output.txt

```
http://user:password@website.com/members/sets/001/somethingfixed-001.zip
http://user:password@website.com/members/sets/002/somethingfixed-002.zip
...
http://user:password@website.com/members/sets/150/somethingfixed-150.zip
```

Comment: Hello David, I tried your program but this is what I get:
http://user:password@website.com/members/sets/0%A/something.zip
http://user:password@website.com/members/sets/0%A/something.zip
it doesn't really add any number. I tried to put 1 to 150 and that was the result for 150 lines.. thanks for giving me some basic info on this though :)

Comment: @draeke - Interesting, because it works fine for me.  Did you copy it exactly as it is above or make modifications?  What OS are you using?  From the results you provided it is not expanding `%%A` into the numeric value, but using it literally.  Are you using `A` as the loop variable and not another letter?

Comment: I tried this now, I made some progress but still can't end this.. I am tryint to learn but i don't know where I do a mistake now:

@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
echo LeftXRight Gen

set /p "Start=Begin = "
set /p "End=End = "
>output.txt ( <nul set /p "=" )
for /L %%A in (%Start%, 1, %End%) do (
    set "X=00%%A"
    echo http://user:pass@website.com/members/sets/!!X:~-3!!/something-!!X:~-3!!.zip>>output.txt
)
endlocal

I really am lost, where's the mistake now? I think I'd rather have a system where I will specify what I need exactly, afterall is easy to modify

Comment: @draeke  The issue with what is shown in your comment are the double eclamations `!!X:~-3!!` should be `!X:~-3!`.  Note, that I have updated my answer with a complete solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I learned something anyhow, but I have no idea where I could study something of this.. is this basic?

Comment: @draeke  My pleasure. **:)**  Learning batch takes much trial and error.  However, there are some great online resources to bookmark if you want to learn more and have great references.  [SS64](http://ss64.com/), [DosTips](http://www.dostips.com/), [Rob VanderWoude](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/), [ComputerHope](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon.htm), and [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772390(v=ws.10).aspx).  Also utilize Stack Overflow and the forums at DosTips and ComputerHope.

Answer (score 0):

This gets near what you are after, with a couple of limitations..

It can only append to the end of the url.

1 and 2 digit numbers are not zero prefixed.

```
@echo off

set /p url="Enter URL: "
set /p start="Start Number: "
set /p end="End Number: "

for /L %%X in (%start%, 1, %end% ) do echo %url% %%X >> file.txt
```

Comment: I tried this too but it creates a result like this:
http://user:password@website.com/members/zips/ 1 
http://user:password@website.com/members/zips/ 2 
http://user:password@website.com/members/zips/ 3 

there is a space before the numbers, no zeros and also there is not the second part...

I will see if I can learn from your examples though, thanks :)

Comment: I tried this:
@echo off

set /p url="Enter URL: "
set /p url2="Enter Second Part: "
set /p start="Start Number: "
set /p end="End Number: "

for /L %%X in (%start%, 1, %end% ) do echo %url%00%%X%url200%%X >> file.txt

didn't really work too well :D